# Cannot convert a string to a class name

Tags: c#

I have a string and need to convert it into a class `Name`.

For example, I have the class :

```
public class Account 
{
    public double Quantity { get; set; }    
    public double Amount{ get; set; }
}
```

And I need to convert:

```
String x = "Account"
```

to the name of that class

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at `Type.GetType`

Comment: *Why* do you want that? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? You can use reflection to create types, invoke methods by name but it's rather cumbersome. Usually, there are far easier ways to do what you want, eg use an IoC container, or a Factory method to generate instances based on some parameter

Comment: this is an example : 

I have this method :

IList<T> List<T>() where T : class;


String X = "account" ;

var Y = convert the string to an instance of the class.


I want to have this :

var accounts = DataAccessServicesProvider.List<Y>();

Comment: In c# 6.0 you can use new nameof operator : `var s = nameof(MyClass);`

Comment: But i work with c# 4.0.Thank you guys